# Max size of Jpeg2000 image

Tags: image-processing, jpeg, codec, image-compression, jpeg2000

According to Jpeg2000 specs, Xsiz & Ysiz can have values ranging from 1 to (2pow32 -1). That means Max size of jpeg2000 file should be (2pow32 -1)*(2pow32 -1) which is very huge.

Am I missing anything here? or Is there any other limitation on the Xsiz, Ysiz or image size?

Comment: can you please quote and name your source? I am not aware of a specific size limit

Comment: and even if there is a limit for width and height, the maximum file size is definitely not width * height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum resolution of a JPEG 2000 compliant codestream is, as you point out, 2^32-1 x 2^32-1 pixels. However:

- It is the *decompressed* file that will have a maximum size of pixels 2^32-1 x 2^32-1. However, to obtain the actual decompressed file size you need to multiply that by the number of components and the number of bytes per sample.
- As Piglet points out, the *compressed* file size will (hopefully) be smaller, that's the whole point of image compression: producing compressed files smaller than the uncompressed images.
- Even though compliant codestreams may have up to that resolution, it doesn't mean that your encoder/decoder implementation necessarily support images that big. JPEG 2000 introduced the concept of "compliance class", which is a system of guarantees of the minimum dimensions (among other things) supported by a given implementation. In practice, you're probably better off testing what the maximum supported size is.